# Problem with Graphic card

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, motherboard

I have problem with my new laptop that is an MSI Alpha 17-A4DE.

The harware on my laptop is:
AMD® Ryzen 5 4600h with radeon graphics × 12
AMD® Radeon rx 5600m / AMD® Renoir

Hello
(For infomation I dont have problem with the laptop screen).

I try to figure oute that every time I set one of the screen MSI or lenovo to primary screeen they will start too lag. It dosent matter which port I use ( HDMI og C1 port) it is when I set them to primary screen the problem appear.

An other problem are that only the screen connected to the HDMI works but when I disconect the HDMI screen the screen connected to C1 start to work.

I hope there are an way of fixing this :)

Thanks

Comment: The way you describe it all 3 monitors are plugged directly into the laptop? If that is not the case add the missing info to the question.

Comment: Hello I use to extra screen one is an lenovo and the other is an MSI screen. The third is the laptopp and it is working fine. It now seams the problem lies with the MSI screen. So I try get some updated driver for this.

Comment: Hello again I figure oute that every time I set one of the screen MSI or lenovo to primary screeen they will start too lag. It dosent matter which port I use ( HDMI og C1 port) it is when I set them to primary screen. An other problem are that only the screen connected to the HDMI works but when I disconect the HDMI the screen that ar connectet to the C1 start to work.

Comment: Add this info to the question via edit.

Comment: Hello just want to tell that now all of my screen are working. I was unplugging the screen connected to HDMI. When doing so the screeen connected to the C1 port started to work and when reconnect rhe HDMI screnn all of them worked nice. I guess it was one of the update that did it, because I tryed this with disconnect and connect earlier and it dident work.

Comment: I am wery happy that it is now working and I can use all of my screen what I need after I set up ODM (Open Drone Map). Well I'm having trouble setting up Docker in Ubuntu, but I'm taking a break now and I'm going to take it from the beginning with ODM now at least one probelm is solved :D